# After All Images Load, Image Tag, Image Object, and Background Image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a background image, an `<img>`, and 5 separate canvas layers *(making up 5 customizable parts of the hammock shown)*. I need to wait for all 3 of these images to load fully into their respective `{display:none;}` elements, and then fade them all in at once.

After some research, I found the library [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/). In the documentation, I know I can use it for an  and a background image, but I'm not sure about an image object (which I'm using to load the canvas images).

Problems:

1) It still loads them separately and fadeIn doesn't wait.

2) In console, `count` increments at odd numbers for some reason, e.g. 1, 3, 5, 7, 11

3) Also, any of these images could already be cached upon load.

I know this code isn't the cleanest or most efficient. I plan to clean it up after getting the basic concept down.  If imagesLoaded isn't the best way to go, what would you recommend?  I just want something that works.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kevmon/6wn6rqe5/20/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="logo"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Dell_Logo.png"/></div>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas4" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas5" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  height:1000px;
  width:1000px;
  position: relative;
  display:none;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 400px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
#canvas1 {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:none;
}
#canvas2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:none;
}
#canvas3 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:none;
}
#canvas4 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:none;
}
#canvas5 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var canvas3 = document.getElementById('canvas3');
var canvas4 = document.getElementById('canvas4');
var canvas5 = document.getElementById('canvas5');
var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
var context3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');
var context4 = canvas4.getContext('2d');
var context5 = canvas5.getContext('2d');

var count = 0;

var img1 = new Image();
var img2 = new Image();
var img3 = new Image();
var img4 = new Image();
var img5 = new Image();

img1.src = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1408/4812/t/11/assets/single-side-main-burgundy.png';
img2.src = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1408/4812/t/11/assets/single-side-secondary-aqua.png';
img3.src = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1408/4812/t/11/assets/single-side-pouch1-aqua.png';
img4.src = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1408/4812/t/11/assets/single-side-pouch2-aqua.png';
img5.src = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1408/4812/t/11/assets/single-side-pouch3-aqua.png';


$("#container").css("background-image", "url(http://www.hotel-r.net/im/hotel/ba/house-3.jpg)"); 
img1.onload = function() {
  context1.drawImage(img1, 0 , 0, 1000, 1000);
}
img2.onload = function() {
  context2.drawImage(img2, 0 , 0, 1000, 1000);
}
img3.onload = function() {
  context3.drawImage(img3, 0 , 0, 1000, 1000);
}
img4.onload = function() {
  context4.drawImage(img4, 0 , 0, 1000, 1000);
}
img5.onload = function() {
  context5.drawImage(img5, 0 , 0, 1000, 1000);
}

function fadeInAll(speed) {
  $("#container").fadeIn(speed);
  $("#canvas1").fadeIn(speed);
  $("#canvas2").fadeIn(speed);
  $("#canvas3").fadeIn(speed);
  $("#canvas4").fadeIn(speed);
  $("#canvas5").fadeIn(speed);
  $('#logo').fadeIn(speed);
}

$('#container').imagesLoaded( { background: true }, function() {
  count++;
  afterAllLoading();
});
$('#logo').imagesLoaded( function() {
  count++;
  afterAllLoading();
});
$('img1').imagesLoaded( function() {
  count++;
  afterAllLoading();
});
$('img2').imagesLoaded( function() {
  count++;
  afterAllLoading();
});
$('img3').imagesLoaded( function() {
  count++;
  afterAllLoading();
});
$('img4').imagesLoaded( function() {
  count++;
  afterAllLoading();
});
$('img5').imagesLoaded( function() {
  count++;
  afterAllLoading();
});

function afterAllLoading() {
        console.log(count++);
    if (count >= 7) {
        fadeInAll(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ironically, your issue is with `console.log(count++)`. This will increment the `count` as well, making it hit `7` before desired. So, only half of the images will be loaded by the time your `fadeInAll` method is called. You should call `console.log(count)` instead.

That will probably work - but I suggest simplifying the code a bit by just having a parent container element around all of the canvases, then setting that parent's `display` to `none`. Then, you need only worry about fading in and out one parent element instead of 7 children, and they will always fade in and out together.